# Proof that solutions approach the nearest equilibria as $t \to \infty$ (if it exists) for a continuous first-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

So I am currently going through *Differential Dynamical Systems* by J.D. Meiss, and when discussing the dynamics of one-dimensional systems, it is noted that solutions tend towards the nearest equilibrium point (assuming it exists). I want to check my own proof, and also ask what am I missing from what Meiss says.

**The situation at hand**

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and that a solution to the IVP $\dot{x} = f(x), \ x(0) = x_0$ exists. Further suppose that $f(x_0) > 0$, and that $f(x) = 0$ for some point $x > x_0$. Let $x^{*}$ be the first zero of $f$ above $x$; then we know that $f(x) > 0$ on $[x_0, x^{*})$. We want to show that $x(t) \to x^{*}$ as $t \to \infty$. (The situation for $f(x_0) < 0$ is similar)

Meiss says that by continuity of $f$, we find that $f(x(t)) \to 0$ as $x \to \xi$. But shouldn't this imply that $f(x(t)) \to f(\xi) >0$ instead? In fact, I believe that I am using this fact to derive a contradiction in my proof later.

**My proposed proof is as follows:**

Clearly, $x(t)$ is bounded above by $x^{*}$, because if $x$ ever hits $x^{*}$ it becomes constant. So suppose that $x(t) \to \xi < x^{*}$ as $t \to \infty$. Due to continuity of $f$ and $f(x) > 0$ on $[x_0, x^{*})$, we know that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-\xi|<\delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(\xi)| < f(\xi)/2$, i.e. that $f(x) > f(\xi)/2 > 0$. Additionally, by our assumption on $x(t)$ as $t \to \infty$, there also exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $t > M$ implies $|x(t) - \xi| < \delta$. Combining these two statements, we find that $t > M$ implies $f(x) = \dot{x} > C$, for some constant $C > 0$.

From this, we can use MVT on the interval $[M, M+k]$ for any integer $k$ to find that there exists $c \in (M, M+k)$ such that $x(M+k) - x(M) = k\dot{x}(c) > kC$, i.e. $x(M+k) > kC + x(M)$. Hence, we have found a sequence $t_k = M+k$ such that $x(t_k)$ is unbounded, contradicting the fact that $x(t) \to \xi$ as $t \to \infty$.

The proof for $f(x_0) < 0$ would be similar, so solutions to our IVP will tend towards the nearest equilibrium point if $f(x_0) \ne 0$. Am I correct in saying that this doesn't necessarily hold if $f(x_0) = 0$, e.g. if we consider $\dot{x} = x^{2/3}, \ x_0 = 0$?